# Why isn't this nested css style being applied?

Tags: css

style:

```
.airport-selections {
    margin-top: 10px;

    .airport-input {
        width: 200px;
    }
}
```

html:

```
<div class="airport-selections">
    <label class="airport-label" for="airport-from">
        Departure:     
    </label>
    <input type="text" class="airport-input">
</div>
```

If I don't nest them, the width of the input is set to 200. This also happens with all of the styles on the page.

Comment: Regular CSS doesn’t support such a nested syntax – only CSS preprocessors, such as LESS, SASS, etc. do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSS is invalid, there is no such thing as nesting in CSS. Only Less or Sass, but you have a long way until then.

If you want to select elements from inside others, use

```
.father .child{
    yourstyle
}
```

All elements with class child from inside all elements with class father will get the style applied to them.

```css
.airport-selections {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.airport-input {
    width: 200px;
}

/*or 

.airport-selections .airport-input {
   width: 200px;
}
*/
```

```html
<div class="airport-selections">
    <label class="airport-label" for="airport-from">Departure:</label>
    <input type="text" class="airport-input">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without a CSS precompiler, there's no such thing as nested CSS styles.

Check out SASS, or LESS for nesting and other options. But what you have there doesn't do what you think it does.